# Cygwin: color coding and branch info for git?

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, git-bash

I just recently changed my client from Git Bash to Cygwin but I am missing color coding when I do `git status` for example and also the bash prompt doesn't include the current branch / rebase etc.

Does anyone know how to make Cygwin look like Git Bash?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to set up your [`.gitconfig`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for your cygwin shell to enable coloured output. Here is what I have in my `~/.gitconfig` file (with which I get coloured markup in the output):

```
[color]
        diff = auto
        status = auto
        branch = auto
        interactive = auto
        ui = true
        pager = true
```

I think the most important line here is `ui = true`, which you can turn on straight from the command line if you wish:

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

Comment: great! that was it :-) but are you aware of how to change the prompt to include everything that is include in gitbash i.e. when you checkout a branch it shows the branch, also when rebasing etc?

Comment: Strange. I've loaded up Git Bash on my computer and its output is not in colour! The only thing I can recommend is to load up your original Git Bash (with colour) and type `cat ~/.gitconfig` to see what settings you are currently using. And then copy those to your cygwin's `.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer by @lee-netherton is correct.

For those using Windows Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201 - I had to create a ~/.bashrc to enable color output from git status.

`[~/.bashrc]`

```
TERM=cygwin
export TERM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `~/.bashrc` prompt that includes git branch:

```
get_git_branch() {
    git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null
}

PS1='\[\e[96m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]($(get_git_branch)) \[\e[0m\]\$ '
```

Result:

```
/current/dir (feature/branch) $
```